# declaring a variable without returning a value .

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys i am new to Jquery and JS in general and have a very simple question basically i came across a sorting script online and i tried to understand whats going on by going through the jquery documentation :

the script is as follows :

```
$(function () {
        var buttons = $('#fruit,#vegetable,#meat').click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            var classes = buttons.filter('.active').map(function() {
                return this.id;
            })
            .get().join(',.');
            $('div.fruit,div.vegetable,div.meat').hide().
                filter('.' + (classes || 'none')).show();               
                console.log(classes.get().join(',.'));
        });
    });
```

and this script is run on the following HTML :

```
<div style="float:right; padding:25px;">
            <button id="fruit" class="active"><span>fruit</span></button>
            <button id="vegetable" class="active">vegetable</button>
            <button id="meat" class="active">meat</button>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p>Trying to use buttons as an "or" case rather than "and." When choosing fuit or vegetable, I want to see tomato as part of each list, <em>not just</em> when both are selected.</p>  

        <div class="fruit">
            <p>apple</p>
        </div>

        <div class="vegetable">
            <p>pumpkin</p>
        </div>

        <div class="vegetable">
           <p>okra</p>
        </div>

        <div class="fruit">
            <p>orange</p>
        </div>

        <div class="meat">
            <p>beef</p>
        </div>    


        <div class="fruit vegetable">
            <p>tomato</p>
        </div>    

        </div>
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/61nc1rpk/12/).

now i understand most part of the script except the following :

on line four of the script the author is using the following code :

```
                var classes = buttons.filter('.active').map(function() {
```

now button has not been returned any value , so should't it be empty ??

or is it that by saying the following (on line one):

```
            var buttons = $('#fruit,#vegetable,#meat').click(function() {
```

the author has also defined the button implicitly , as in :

```
var buttons = $('#fruit,#vegetable,#meat')
```

can somebody clarify this for me , as i am struggling to grasp this simple concept .

Thank you.

Alex-Z.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an unusual pattern, but `buttons` is indeed declared correctly (and *explicitly*`) in the statement reading:

```
var buttons = $(...).click(...);
```

By the time any `click` event ever happens the above code will have executed (since JS is single-threaded) and `buttons` will already contain the desired set of elements and can be safely used within the callback.

This also of course relies on the way that many jQuery methods "chain" - they return the same object as the one on which they were called, so the net result is that `buttons` does just contain `$('#fruit,#vegetable,#meat')`

Comment: I think a note about jQuery's method chaining is also needed.

Comment: so basically the value of button is `var buttons = $('#fruit,#vegetable,#meat')` .

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik yes, it is. `.click()` returns the same jQuery's object.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Not because of how javascript works, but rather because of how jQuery works. It's crucial that you understand the `buttons` holds whatever `.click` returns. Not `$('#fruit,#vegetable,#meat')`. It's just jQuery that will *make it so* (see Utkanos answer) that both are the same.

Answer (score 4):

Your assumption is correct. `buttons` is defined at the same time as a click event is bound to it. This is true of most jQuery methods that run on elements (i.e. returned by a selector) rather than static methods of the jQuery namespace itself. So:

```
var els = $('*').filter('.foo').attr('class', 'bar');
```

returns the elements matched by `*` and `.foo`, whilst *at the same time* setting the class `bar`.

jQuery uses what's called the chaining pattern - that is, methods are chained one after another - and it's this sort of inferred assignment that some people have against this pattern. As you have found, if you're not too savvy with this pattern, assignment can be difficult to infer.

Comment: Thanks alot , i am just curious , is ur definition of infer = "to find out" ??

Comment: It means to deduce from the available evidence. From your name, I wonder if you speak Russian, in which case: заключать.

Comment: The problem with chaining shows up when there is super-duper long line with a lot of methods calls. It is difficult to read and it does many actions in one line, which again is not good programming style.

Comment: @Regent - yeap, agreed. That's why some consider it an anti-pattern.